# Is Qualcomm Snapdragon Android SDK for face recognition, open source or paid version.

Tags: android, camera, face-detection

i am new to android and i am trying to make a face recognition app.I searched many sdk's and finally i liked the qualcomm's snapdragon face recognition android sdk. But i unable to know one thing about this sdk . Is it open source or not. can we use it for free? And how can i know the expiry period if any for this sdk. So I'm stuck, any work around solutions you guys are aware of?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The [license agreement](https://developer.qualcomm.com/content/snapdragon-processor-software-development-kit) includes this text,

> You shall not engage in any act or failure to act, that enables, causes or facilitates any use or distribution of the Software or any third-party software in a manner that causes any patents, copyrights or other intellectual property rights owned or controlled by QTI or any of its affiliates (or for which QTI or any of its affiliates has received license rights) to become subject to any encumbrance or terms and conditions of any Open Source License.

It's not an Open Source license in any way shape or form. As for it's price, I cannot say - I will not agree to be bound by their license terms.

Comment: Thank you, can you please suggest me any sdk that is open source and works effectively. I also checked the luxand face recognition sdk, but it is not so effective to recognise faces when lighting is little dim and ofcourse dark faces too.